# Return the version of glibc to 2.12

Tags: linux, centos-6, glibc

on CentOS release 6.9 (Final)

I have updated glibc to 2.14 according to this procedure

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176489/how-to-update-glibc-to-2-14-in-centos-6-5

However after upgrading some programs can't work and segmentation fault.

Especially somehow even apache doesn't work.

How can I back to the old version??

```
mkdir ~/glibc_install; cd ~/glibc_install 

wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.14.tar.gz

tar zxvf glibc-2.14.tar.gz

cd glibc-2.14

mkdir build

cd build

../configure --prefix=/opt/glibc-2.14

make -j4

sudo make install

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/glibc-2.14/lib
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those are the instructions you followed, all you should need to do is `unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and delete `/opt/glibc-2.14`. If you put the `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH` line in a system startup file, make sure to delete it from there too.

Comment: Thanks for your help . At that time I was a bit panic afraid to have broken my server. I solved my problem.